# BaseHost URL setting in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using the latest version of `RestSharp`. I am wanting to set the Base URL so i can change it at a later date but **only** the domain would change and lower level URLs would always remain the same. Example

> www.example.com/api/customers

> www.example.com/api/customers/1

would become

> www.newdomain.com/api/customers

> www.newdomain.com/api/customers/1

Using this code works

```
 var rest = new RestClient();
 rest.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://www.example.com/api/customers/");
 var restReq = new RestRequest();
 RestResponse resp = rest.Execute<CustomerModel>(restReq);
```

I tried to change the above code to (setting the `BaseHost`)

```
 var rest = new RestClient();
 rest.Options.BaseHost = "https://www.example.com";// Will move this to a config later
 rest.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri("/api/customers/");
 var restReq = new RestRequest();
 RestResponse resp = rest.Execute<CustomerModel>(restReq);
```

but receive the standard error about the URI not being in the correct format.

I know i can use something like `Path.Combine(baseDomain,rest.Options.BaseUrl)` but then it leaves me wondering why the second posted code doesnt work when setting the `BaseHost`?

I couldnt find anything on the documentation to explain this either?

Answer (score 2):

You should may want to use `RestSharp` like this:

```cs
var rest = new RestClient("https://www.example.com");
var restReq = new RestRequest("/api/customers/");
RestResponse resp = rest.ExecuteAsync<CustomerModel>(restReq);
```

This way you set the `BaseURL` on 1st line, and then on the 2nd you set the path of your API, which should not change.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that as it doesn't work with my version of Dependency Injection which is why I have it broken down into the above format

Comment: Which part does not work? because you could set your `BaseURL` the old way, and set the paths the way I showed.

Comment: If I declare the RestClient in my DI with a parameter then it doesn't work. If I set it as a singleton instance and then pass in the URL (in my first code block) then it works.